# Cannot install data.table package on R 3.3.0

Tags: r, installation, data.table

I tried to install the 'data.table' package with R 3.3.0, but it returns the given error as below. I installed all required packages, but it did not help me at all.

I googled for the same issue, but there's nothing.

Please share your experience to fix it, if you had the same problem. It is very strange to me now.

Thanks a lot,
Sean

```
> install.packages('data.table')
Installing package into ‘/usr/lib64/R/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 3233k  100 3233k    0     0  2098k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 2205k
* installing *source* package ‘data.table’ ...
** package ‘data.table’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c assign.c -o assign.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c between.c -o between.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c bmerge.c -o bmerge.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c chmatch.c -o chmatch.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c dogroups.c -o dogroups.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c fastmean.c -o fastmean.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c fcast.c -o fcast.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c fmelt.c -o fmelt.o
gcc -m64 -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/../../include/R -DNDEBUG  -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/zlib -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/xz -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include/bzip2 -I/builddir/build/BUILD/R-3.3.0/port/Linux-X64/include    -fopenmp -fpic  -g -O2  -c forder.c -o forder.o
forder.c: In function ‘range_str’:
forder.c:296: error: expected end of line before ‘update’
make: *** [forder.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘data.table’
* removing ‘/usr/lib64/R/library/data.table’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpCfSYUU/downloaded_packages’
Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'
Making 'packages.html' ... done
Warning message:
In install.packages("data.table") :
  installation of package ‘data.table’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: try adding `install.packages("data.table", dependencies = T)`?

Comment: What does `gcc --version` say, ie what is your compiler?

Comment: Line 296 of `forder.c` is `#pragma omp atomic update`. So Dirk is correct to ask `gcc --version` since that determines version of OpenMP iiuc.  I don't know when `gcc` started to support `atomic update` but I thought a very long time ago.

Comment: gcc version is 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6) (GCC).

Comment: For what it's worth: I had a similar issue with R 3.5.0 on a centOS cluster, and the package compiled fine via `BiocManager::install` after loading gcc 4.9.0 through our "module" system.

Comment: By installing the latest GCC from Software Collection Library (Devtoolset-8) and then enabling it, I could install the package successfully.